# "cool" used to describe a person

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was reading the *about me* page on an author of a poker strategy website and on one of the passages he describes himself as a pretty *cool* guy:

> This is the page where you get to read a little more about me and subsequently find out that the guy behind such a sophisticated Texas Hold em website is actually really cool.

I looked up the meaning of *cool* and it seems like when it's used to describe a person, its meaning is negative. From OALD *cool* used with persons means:

> 1. not friendly, interested or enthusiastic
> 2. calm and confident in a way that lacks respect for other people, but makes people admire you as well as disapprove

So what does he mean when he describes himself as "cool"?

Comment: This article explores the different meanings that *cool* has when applied to a person: http://articles.latimes.com/2012/nov/10/health/la-he-whats-cool-20121110

Comment: Which kinds of people may like a rude person with a fake confidence?! I guess something is wrong in the definition: 1. It is about sadomasochistic relationship between ill minded people 2. Wrong information from a narcissist person! Anyway if it is what cool is I prefer non-cool people! :)(

Comment: Telling people you are cool is very uncool.  I assume he is not being serious and is really saying "I know, I'm a bit of a poker geek" in a self-deprecating way.  (Not sure why he feels its necessary to say that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He means definition 3. from *Oxford Advanced American Dictionary*. Specifically, see their second example.

> 3 (informal) used to show that you admire or approve of something or someone because they are fashionable, attractive, and often different
>
> - You look pretty cool with that new haircut.
> - Dave's a really cool guy.
> - It's a cool movie.

When applied to people (e.g. *"pretty cool guy*"), I would say it is more likely to mean *interesting* and *different* than *fashionable* and *attractive*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "cool" is slang and I think he means 2. but without the "lack respect" part.